# How can i add Existing ENI as Eth0 in AWS Cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have ENI (eni-0c6f3e911XXX) and want to add this as Eth0 in EC2 using cloud-formation template . Ec2 should have only this interface.

Thanks
AN

Answer (score 0):

In cloudformation you can specify your ENI by it's ID

```
MyEC2Instance" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
   "Properties" : {
      "ImageId" : "ami-79fd7eee",
      "KeyName" : "testkey",
      "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
          "NetworkInterfaceId" : String,
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: The `DeviceIndex` property of the `NetworkInterface` object must be provided. It's value should be `0`.

Comment: Also, do not specify `SecurityGroupIds` or `SubnetId` directly on the instance when doing this. These properties will be used from the `eth0` ENI.